# TypeError: middleware is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to apply redux in my reactjs app. I can't proceed because of these errors:

[image]

[image]

I'm sure that I already installed all the dependencies that I need. Here is a relevant part of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
   "redux": "^3.7.2",
   "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
   "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
}
```

Here is a part of my index.js that implements redux

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import reducers from './reducers';

const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(reducers,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware, logger
    )
)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger) you are mixing up the usage of `redux-logger`

You either need to import the specific `createLogger` function

```
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'

const logger = createLogger({
  // ...options
});
```

Or use the default import

```
import logger from 'redux-logger'
```

And then your code should be fine

```
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! using the default import and passing it to the applyMiddleware works for me. Also, thanks for referencing the doc.

Answer (score 5):

```
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reduxPromiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(reduxPromiseMiddleware, thunk, logger);
const store = createStore(reducer, middleware);
```

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error *TypeError: middleware is not a function*.

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import math from "./reducers/mathReducer";
import user from "./reducers/userReducer";

const logger = createLogger();

export default createStore(
  combineReducers({ math, user }),
  {},
  applyMiddleware(logger, thunk)
);
```

Replacing `applyMiddleware(logger, thunk)` with `applyMiddleware(logger, thunk.default)` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way to fix the issue

```
import * as thunk from 'redux-thunk';



createStore(rootReducer, InitialState, applyMiddleware(thunk.default));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see react and react-dom in your dependencies, and it is not included in the import statements.

Let me provide you with an example of how I did an App recently, also using the redux developer tools which is amazing.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './components/App';
import authReducer from '../reducers/auth';
import urlsReducer from '../reducers/urls';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

//Store creation
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      auth: authReducer,
      urls: urlsReducer
    }),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
  );

ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

I would figure that you just need to add logger, after reduxThunk. And if you have already combined your reducers, then just provide reducers instead of combineReducers.

Regards,
Rafael

Answer (score 2):

Simply add **.default** to the **createStore** function and solve the error **Middleware is not a function**.[image]

Comment: Can you explain why this works? 
and also where can i read more about this

Answer (score 2):

I was using version 3.1.0 on React 18.2.0 and NextJS 11.1.4 when I got this error and my problem was solved by changing the Redux-thunk version to 2.3.0

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35449625)

Answer (score 1):

Please find below code for the solution:

```
const thunkMiddleware = require('redux-thunk').default;

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add `logger` to the list of middleware only in development but messed up the import and received the same error. To fix my issue, I needed to add `.default` to the `require()`:

```js
const middleware = []

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  middleware.push(require('redux-logger').default)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was calling middleware function before the store method

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, what [@anisur-rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6116595/anisur-rahman) suggested above worked for me. I just made the change from `applyMiddleware(logger) to applyMiddleware(logger.default)`. I hope this helps and many thanks to @anisur-rahman for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I call the `ThunkMiddleware` and pass it in to the `applyMiddleware` method. To fix the issue I used the following code :

```
const createStore = redux.createStore;
const applyMiddleware = redux.applyMiddleware;

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FEATCH_USERS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case FEATCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };
    case FEATCH_USERS_FAILURE:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: [],
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware.thunk));
```