# When calling createStore() I get: TypeError: middleware is not a function

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-middleware

Before flagging this has duplicates note that I have checked:

- [How to dispatch a Redux action with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559)
- [TypeError: middleware is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869671/typeerror-middleware-is-not-a-function)
- [× TypeError: middleware is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664110/%C3%97-typeerror-middleware-is-not-a-function)

I am trying to integrate `redux-thunk` and use replace `replaceReducer` on my Redux store at the same time.

Basically, I have somewhere:

```
const {createStore, applyMiddleware} = require('redux');
const thunk = require('redux-thunk');
createStore(function() {return {}}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
// also tried
// createStore(function() {return {}}, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

And later:

```
store.replaceReducer(someCombinedReducer);
```

Right now, I am getting an error triggered through the `createStore()` line (so before any reducer replacement).

```
TypeError: middleware is not a function
```

---

Versions:

- redux: 4.0.1
- redux-thunk: 2.3.0

EDIT:

The stack trace is pointing to the `applyMiddleware` function exactly as in this question [TypeError: middleware is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869671/typeerror-middleware-is-not-a-function) directly from the call I make.

Comment: Can you give more details on where that error is coming from?  Is it an actual runtime error?  A TypeScript error?  Is there a stack trace?

Comment: @markerikson edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night of sleep and some tweaking.

```
// thunk here is not undefined but and object
const thunk = require('redux-thunk');
```

Should be replaced by:

```
const thunk = require('redux-thunk').default;
```